# onEdit not seeing pasted changes, google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a cell counter in (J1) that counts every time cell (J2) has changed, finally got the counter to work, but I noticed that it only "sees" manual edits and does not count any copy-pasted values (I'm pasting values directly into cell J2). Is there anyway to fix this as manually typing in the value would defeat the whole purpose.

This is what I have so far

```
function onEdit(e) {
  incrementCounter_(e);
}

/**
* Increments a counter in a cell when another cell is edited.
*
* @param {Object} e The event object.
*/
function incrementCounter_(e) {
  var sheetToWatch = 'Work Order';
  var cellToWatch = 'J2';
  var cellToIncrement = 'J1';
  if (!e || !e.range) {
    return;
  }
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() === sheetToWatch && e.range.getA1Notation() === cellToWatch) {
    var cell = sheet.getRange(cellToIncrement);
    cell.setValue((Number(cell.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can determine the size of your edited range with event object properies like columnStart, columnEnd, rowStart and rowEnd and then create code to deal with pasting.  Although the oldValue will only be able to hold the previous value of the cell in the upper left corner of the edited range.

Comment: When you say copy pasted value are you still intending that to mean user edits or not?

Comment: onEdit triggers only fire on user edits

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I'm copying and pasting client names directly into cell J2

Comment: Your original script actually already works. I'm not sure what happened but testing it seems to do the expected. I think there is something wrong on where you are trying it on. Also, both answers below also work. Share a sheet where you tried the script and let us check the actual execution.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mwG4BT4LnF6qTdr7OlDrEdwRAs0pk_EuvFs3AX3-GB8/edit?usp=sharing              I copy the row with the client i want (on sheet2) and paste it where the clients name will go (J2), the cell counter (J1) does not change unless manually editing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet()
  for (var i = e.range.rowStart;i<=e.range.rowEnd;i++){
    for (var j = e.range.columnStart;j<=e.range.columnEnd;j++){
      incrementCounter_(sh.getRange(i,j),sh)
    }
  }
}
function incrementCounter_(rng,sh) {
  var sheetToWatch = 'Work Order';
  var cellToWatch = 'J2';
  var cellToIncrement = 'J1';
  if (sh.getName() === sheetToWatch && rng.getA1Notation() === cellToWatch) {
    var cell = sh.getRange(cellToIncrement);
    cell.setValue((Number(cell.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
  }
}
```

or

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet()
  var sheetToWatch = 'Work Order';
  if (sh.getName() === sheetToWatch) {
    var cellToWatch = 'J2';
    var cellToIncrement = 'J1';
    for (var i = e.range.rowStart; i <= e.range.rowEnd; i++) {
      for (var j = e.range.columnStart; j <= e.range.columnEnd; j++) {
        if (sh.getRange(i, j).getA1Notation() === cellToWatch) {
          sh.getRange(cellToIncrement).setValue((Number(sh.getRange(cellToIncrement).getValue()) || 0) + 1)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this works!!! not sure why the others didn't work when pasting but thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

If what you mean is pasting into a range where it includes J2 (that doesnt start at J2), then you need to check if J2 is within the edited range.

#### Script:

```
function incrementCounter_(e) {
  var sheetToWatch = 'Work Order';
  var cellToIncrement = 'J1';

  var range = e.range;
  // get the dimension of the range
  var rowStart = range.getRow();
  var rowEnd = range.getLastRow();
  var colStart = range.getColumn();
  var colEnd = range.getLastColumn();
  // boolean if range edited does not include J2 (2, 10)
  var invalidRange = rowStart > 2 || rowEnd < 2 || colStart > 10 || colEnd < 10;

  // return if range is invalid
  if (!e || !e.range || invalidRange){
    return;
  }
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  // range should be valid (negated boolean value)
  if (sheet.getName() === sheetToWatch && !invalidRange) {
    var cell = sheet.getRange(cellToIncrement);
    cell.setValue((Number(cell.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
  }
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- `onEdit` is only triggered by user edits.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! I'm pasting a client name directly into cell J2, I tried the above script and can't seem to get it to work though

Comment: @DaniBear, that's weird, it should work. The script above should also support that. In the gif output above, it can be seen that I pasted "qwe" during the 3rd edit of J2 and J1's 15 was iterated to 16. It works with either ctrl + v, or right click then paste is done. Can you create a blank sheet and test the script above from scratch?

Comment: tested on a blank sheet doesn't seem to work, neither hand typing or pasting

Comment: can you please share that sample sheet here?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mwG4BT4LnF6qTdr7OlDrEdwRAs0pk_EuvFs3AX3-GB8/edit?usp=sharing              I copy the row with the client i want (on sheet2) and paste it where the clients name will go (J2), the cell counter (J1) does not change unless manually editing - When trying yours the cell counter does not change at all even during manual edits, so i must be doing something completely wrong altogether